# Trying to get Product Name and product ID into url with slash at the end and in between without ?p=

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I guess the title almost says it all.

My original url looks like: `http://www.something.com/buy/index.php?p=025823`

The .htaccess I'm using looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ./index.php?p=$1
```

The resulting url looks like: `http://www.something.com/buy/025823`

I'd like to end up with a url like: `http://www.something.com/buy/Product Name/025823/`

Can anyone help? Especially that Gumbo fella! LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can control the links that are generated to your `/buy/` pages, just insert the product name in the URL (keeping in mind the rules of URLs, like no spaces allowed.  Usually, people substitute a `-` for spaces). Then modify your rewrite regex to ignore the product name portion of your URL.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/buy/(.+)/(\d+)/$ ./index.php?p=$2
```

If you can't control the links, things get more complicated since you'll have to look up the product name using a `RewriteMap` and then perform a redirect.  I just recently covered this is in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332224/having-huge-redirect-list-in-htaccess-a-problem/).  My [answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332224/having-huge-redirect-list-in-htaccess-a-problem/3332248#3332248) goes in to greater detail about using `RewriteMap`, but I don't think the details of that answer apply to your situation since using a statically-defined list of products probably won't meet your needs.

Basically, you'll need to implement a script that can be called from mod_rewrite's `RewriteMap` rule. You'll need something like:

```
RewriteMap prodname pgm:/path/to/script/namelookup.sh
RewriteRule ^/buy/(\d+)/$ /buy/${prodname:$1}/$1/ [R=permanent]
```

Where namelookup.sh (or whatever) returns the product's name (on stdout) in a URL-encoded format.  You'll definitely want to take a look at [mod_rewrite's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) about using `RewriteMap`, specifically the last section of the `RewriteMap Directive` on using an external rewriting program.

Comment: Fantastic! Josh, you da man! I've been trying for two days to get this and neglecting other client's work. Here's what I ended up with. Slightly modified since my .htaccess is in the buy directory. Worked just fine right out of the box. Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.+)/(\d+)/$ ./index.php?p=$2 Thanks again!

Comment: Looks like the comments don't allow for proper paragraphs. Sorry.

Comment: @Douglas: I'm glad I could help.  Since this answer worked for you, remember to click the green checkmark above to mark this answer as accepted and your question resolved.